# protobuf determining message type to deserialize

Tags: java, network-programming, protocol-buffers

With protobuf we can define messages and generate their classes and each will know how to serialize/deserialize to binary.

Suppose we have multiple different messages already defined, 
and we get some byte[] off the wire, how do we determine the message type to use appropriate class and deserialize?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't. Protocol buffers' wire format does not encode the message type, only the tag numbers and types.

For instance, the wire format of instances of messages of the following protos will be identical (with the same data in the string field, obviously):

```
message Foo {
  optional string foo_field = 1;
}

message Bar {
  optional string field_contained_in_bar = 1;
}
```

and an instance of the following message *might* have the same encoding too, if only the string field is set:

```
message Baz {
  optional string str = 1;
  optional int32 num = 2;
}
```

You need to know which message type(s) you are expecting to receive.

Please refer to the examples of the encoding [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding?hl=en).

Comment: what about ANY types in proto 3? i just read about them, but seems those are to solve exactly this issue, and they do contain URI to the type, for java i think it is the full package name... https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/any.proto

Comment: or maybe i must do something like some generic type {string type, bytes message} then decode the generic type then decode depending on 'type' use appropriate class do decdoe target message? (turns out double decoding)

Comment: Yes, the `any` type does, but that is just one field type - what about if your message contains only non-`any` types. any is going to be pretty inefficient to use as a general type, since you have to write the type on every message (since a list of `any`s can contain different types). Plus, you don't know the type of the message containing the field of `any` type.

Comment: so if i have differnt types, i need to do double decoding? is that the solution? like putting an int at first then determine the type by that int then only decode?

Comment: wait the ANY stands for a composit type, it is like a placeholder for entire different message type that is defined somewhere in proto file... so it solves the problem but yes as you said a string with full package name will be included every time...

Comment: which is not that bad as the generic type containing a single ANY will be used only on transport layer, after that you will unpack it to the specific type and use whatever way you want, for example persist...

Comment: essentially if you look at the any.proto it is exactly what i've suggested, just type is represented with string (i suggested int or enum will be better)... so when they implement it they are going to do the same double decoding..