# Is there an alternative to Protobuf that can map serialized messages to its type?

Tags: serialization, deserialization, protocol-buffers

I was disappointed to learn Protobuf can't deserialize and map a message to the type it was serialized from: [protobuf determining message type to deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639905/protobuf-determining-message-type-to-deserialize?rq=1)

For example, when sending messages over a single socket connection we may want to route the message according to its type.

Are there any serialization schemes that can do this?

Comment: The answer you referenced is correct but your inference is incorrect. You can't deserialize arbitrary protobuf messages. That is correct. But you can deserialize messages of a known, standard message type that **encapsulate** arbitrary messages. See [Any](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any). I think this comment likely doesn't change your decision but it does provide a possible approach.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this: Protocol Buffers [self-describing messages](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#self-description)

Comment: All my applications will have an up to date copy of the proto file, but the self-describing message technique is intriguing nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I find the `Any` documentation a little sparse and esoteric, so correct me if I'm wrong, but I can put a whole Protobuf message in an `Any` field on another, generalized Protobuf message, call it `AppMessage`, and send that along? A couple questions arise from that - 1) can the receiver tell the difference between two messages that have the same fields? Or do I need to specify the message type for each `Any` field?  2) Do I need a long switch/case statement to test for every kind of message I expect to receive (I thought Protobuf could help me avoid this)?

Comment: See the protobuf defintion of [`Any`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/01e84b129361913e5613464c857734fcfe095367/src/google/protobuf/any.proto#L154). The message contains a `type_url` and `bytes`. `type_url` is used to provide a unique reference to the message type of `bytes`. Yes, regardless of how you implement this,  you will need to pattern-match on all the incoming message type possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, Protobuf does support this kind of usage in a roundabout kind of way. DazWilkin's answer in the comments about [`Any`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any) pointed me in the right direction.

`Any` is a Google type you can include in a custom Protobuf message, say `WrapperMessage`.

```
message WrapperMessage {
  google.protobuf.Any anyMessage = 1;
}
```

You can pack and unpack other custom Protobuf messages into an `Any`. When unpacking the `Any` message, depending on the client Protobuf library, there will be some way to access a string representing the type, usually `typeUrl`, but some implementations allow access to `fullName`.

From there you should have what you need to switch on this type string and transform the `Any` into the specific Protobuf custom message type needed.